# h:selectOneListbox + a4j:ajax not calling setter

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I'm facing a strange issue, I have a form with a h:selectOneListbox :

```
<h:selectOneListbox value="#{webHostingServicesActions.customPackage.storage}" size="1">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="None" itemValue="#{null}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{webHostingServicesActions.storagesChoices}" var="item" itemLabel="#{item.name}" />
    <f:converter converterId="productConverter" />
    <a4j:ajax event="valueChange" render="lblTotal" />
</h:selectOneListbox>
```

When I select one item from *f:selectItems*, the setter *webHostingServicesActions.customPackage.storage* is not called. But when I select the item from *f:selectItem*, the setter is called properly.

Of course I'm using a custom converter, but it was tested and respond correctly.

Every other ajax actions in the form seems blocked when an item from *f:selectItems* is selected. There is no error on server side, also no error when using *a4j:log* in debug.

**EDIT 1** : When I'm selecting an item from *f:selectItems*, the server-side code to apply request values is executed, but it blocks somewhere before the setter. I wasn't able to trace far enough to see what is happening.

**EDIT 2** : I've added the BalusC LifeCycleListener...

When I select the item from *f:selectItem*

```
START PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
END PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
START PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
END PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
START PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
END PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
START PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
END PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
START PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
END PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
START PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
END PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
```

When I select an item from the *f:selectItems*

```
START PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
END PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
START PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
END PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
START PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
END PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
START PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
END PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
```

I've also tested the *change* instead of *valueChange* and nothing was different.

Any help appreciated thank you!

Alexandre.

Comment: You can start by changing `event="valueChange"` to `event="change"`. `valueChange` is applicable to `EditableValueHolder` components (textboxes etc).

Comment: also did you check if the request processing lifecycle made it past the validations phase? right after apply-request-values

Comment: I've added an <rich:messages globalOnly="false" /> and yes I'm getting a validation error, now I need to find where, since I'm not using any validator...

Comment: `Value not valid`? or what exactly is the error?

Comment: The validation message only told that the value was invalid so it was not very helpful... but it is now fixed thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I found the solution, I had a misconception about using converter with h:selectOneListbox. I was thinking that the converter could be used to convert the Object from the f:selectItems and vice-versa.

I've changed back my code a bit :

```
<h:selectOneListbox value="#{webHostingServicesActions.selectedStorage}" size="1">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Aucun" itemValue="#{null}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{webHostingServicesActions.storagesChoices}" var="item" itemLabel="#{item.name}" itemValue="#{item.keyProduct}" />
    <f:converter converterId="integerConverter" />
    <a4j:ajax event="valueChange" render="lblTotal" />
</h:selectOneListbox>
```

Now the setter *selectedStorage* will receive an *Integer* instead of an object *Product*. Everything works as espected.

Thanks to kolossus putting me on the right way and this post : [Object as itemValue in <f:selectItems>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635302/object-as-itemvalue-in-fselectitems)