# javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException : Illegal Syntax for Set Operation

Tags: jsf, el

I am creating a Java EE + JSF application using primefaces.org and I am getting an exception that I cannot resolve.

Here is the exception I am getting:

```
2017-10-20T11:45:10.085+0200|Severe: javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: /enterpriseEditor.xhtml @59,54 value="#{enterpriseEditor.selectedCountry} ": Illegal Syntax for Set Operation
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:866)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processUpdates(UIInput.java:749)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1291)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1291)
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.processUpdatesOfFacetsAndChilds(ComponentUtils.java:283)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UITabPanel.processUpdates(UITabPanel.java:1108)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabView.processUpdates(TabView.java:337)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processUpdates(UIForm.java:281)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1291)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1291)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processUpdates(UIViewRoot.java:1254)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.UpdateModelValuesPhase.execute(UpdateModelValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: /enterpriseEditor.xhtml @59,54 value="#{enterpriseEditor.selectedCountry} ": Illegal Syntax for Set Operation
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:136)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:832)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: Illegal Syntax for Set Operation
    at com.sun.el.parser.SimpleNode.setValue(SimpleNode.java:168)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.setValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:294)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.setValue(WeldValueExpression.java:64)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:131)
    ... 43 more
```

Here is the markup from enterpriseEditor.xhtml that cases the exception:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="country" value="#{enterpriseEditor.selectedCountry} ">
  <f:selectItems value="#{enterpriseEditor.countries}"
  var="country" itemLabel="#{country.countryName}" itemValue="#{country}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Here is the backing bean behind the markup

```
@Named("enterpriseEditor")
@ViewScoped
public class EnterpriseEditor implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 7623690881971066425L;

private Enterprise enterprise;
private List<Country> countries;
private Country selectedCountry;

public EnterpriseEditor() {
}

public List<Country> getCountries() {
    return countries;
}

public void setCountries(List<Country> countries) {
    this.countries = countries;
}

public Country getSelectedCountry() {
    return selectedCountry;
}

public void setSelectedCountry(Country selectedCountry) {
    this.selectedCountry = selectedCountry;
}
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the setter for `selectedCountry`?

Comment: @Evan I added the getter and setter for selectedCountry

Comment: I suspect it's because you're using an Object as the value - you'll need to either write a converter (like so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635302/object-as-itemvalue-in-fselectitems) or use the ID and set the object after.

Comment: There **_IS_** a space in the value attribute... And comment should be in real comments, not in the edit comment of a question... You are lucky I read (almost) all of them. And you **do** have the error that was added to the title by BalusC...

Comment: My fault, thank you!!!